# Cannot get Mysql 8.0 to stay open in Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos

MySQL suddenly cannot keep open.  I tried 
          ps -ef | grep mysql
          sudo kill -9 5211

I tried removing my my.cnf
I tried creating a new my.cnf as suggested by a previous post

Nothing is working.  mySQL from "System Preference" turns on after I put my password and few seconds later turns off.

Here is the error log:

```
2019-02-14T01:13:17.285925Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 11402

 2019-02-14T01:13:17.288972Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive

 2019-02-14T01:13:17.317235Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2019-02-14T01:13:17.317441Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2019-02-14T01:13:17.317548Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] InnoDB: If you are  installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
 2019-02-14T01:13:17.317666Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] InnoDB: File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
 2019-02-14T01:13:17.317798Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
 2019-02-14T01:15:15.776723Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 12646
 2019-02-14T01:15:15.779642Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
  2019-02-14T01:15:15.796296Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
  2019-02-14T01:15:15.796337Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
   2019-02-14T01:15:15.796352Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
   2019-02-14T01:15:15.796365Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] InnoDB: File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
   2019-02-14T01:15:15.796380Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Here is the error.  I will check what it means.

Comment: Check the logs for the reason it's closing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have removed .cnf file, so it is expecting ./ibdata1 file in current folder and it is not there. Usually data directory is defined in .cnf file with `datadir` property.
e.g

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

And this ibdata1 is in datadir folder.